# How to read pdf from anather app in our app?

Tags: ios, pdf, uidocumentinteraction

I want to read pdf from various application which support pdf (iBook or another),
And I want to browse that pdf in our app.

How can I achieve this?

Plz help me ..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the filesystem directly, due to sandboxing, but you can implement a custom URL scheme that will allow users to open PDF files from Safari, Dropbox etc. in your app.

Comment: You can only tell the OS what file types your app can accept. The other app has to be able to send the file to other apps. See here http://www.madmob.co.za/2011/05/31/opening-custom-files-in-ios-with-your-app/